# How to interrupt Accept method in libfcgi?

Tags: c++, multithreading, fastcgi

I'm coding a FastCGI application using libfcgi (fcgiapp) library. The problem is within `FCGX_Accept_r` method, which waits for incoming connections and blocks thread. As I can see, it doesn't have any kind of timeout, so program flow is unable to continue execution until a request is arrived.

I tried to set `FCGI_FAIL_ACCEPT_ON_INTR` flag in `FCGX_InitRequest` method to make accept function to interrupt, but with no success.

> Setting FCGI_FAIL_ACCEPT_ON_INTR prevents FCGX_Accept() from restarting upon being interrupted.

I also tried calling `FCGX_ShutdownPending`, but it seem to reject **new** incoming connections and not stopping listening for next one.

> Prevent the lib from accepting any new requests. Signal handler safe.

Could you advise me what else can be done to break `FCGX_Accept_r` awaiting?

Comment: @SergeyA Thank you for your concern. I call `FCGX_Accept_r` from within `std::thread` instance. I tried to send SIGTERM and SIGINT to running application, and they are processed by handler function, but this doesn't affect threads with `FCGX_Accept_r` running.

Comment: it needs to be forwarded to the thread which runs this function. You need to set up thread signal disposition in such a way that this thread will see the signal.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, just close the socket:

```
FCGX_Request request;
// ...
close(request.listen_sock);
```

Answer (score 1):

`FCGX_Accept_r` will break out with negative return value on a signal if signal handler `SA_RESTART` flag is not set.

If you want your process to shutdown gracefully on a signal (e.g. SIGINT) register a dummy signal handler like this:

```
struct sigaction act;
sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
act.sa_flags = 0;
act.sa_handler = your_handler;
sigaction(signo, &act, NULL);
```

Make sure to use `sigaction`, `signal` sets `SA_RESTART` flag by default as it affects how certain primitives behave with signals.

> Macro: int **SA_RESTART** This flag controls what happens when a signal is
>   delivered during certain primitives (such as open, read or write), and
>   the signal handler returns normally. There are two alternatives: the
>   library function can resume, or it can return failure with error code
>   EINTR.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. If you are running on linux you need to shutdown the socket to make FCGX_Accept_r return and have FCGI_FAIL_ACCEPT_ON_INTR set.

The code I use to stop FCGI on Linux is:

```
FCGX_ShutdownPending();

if (miSocket != -1)
{
    shutdown(miSocket, SHUT_RD);
}
```